# What is the cin analougus of scanf formatted input?

Tags: c++, input, std

With scanf there's, usually, a direct way to take formatted input:

1) line with a real number higher than 0, and less than 1. Ending on 'x', e.g: *0.32432523x*

```
scanf("0.%[0-9]x", &number);
```

2) line represents an addition in the format *:30+28=fifty-eight*

```
scanf(":%d+%d=%99s", &number1, &number2, &total);
```

What is the cin solution, using only the standard library?

Comment: Nowhere *near* as pretty...  `scanf` is really powerful.  Personally, I read into a `string`, grab the pointer via `string::c_str()` and then `sscanf` it.  Or I tokenise it myself from a `stringstream` or whatever.

Comment: For formatted input like this in C++, you might want to consider something like [Boost Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/). It may be overkill, but it'll be cleaner than using iostreams directly.

Comment: scanf gets the win on this one because it simultaneously gives you a return value that you can check in one place to verify everything matched. In cin stream you'd have to check a few things "manually".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the >> operator to read from cin.

```
  int number1, number2;
  std::string text;
  char plus, equals;
  std::cin >> number1 >> plus >> number2 >> equals >> text;
  if (!std::cin.fail() && plus == '+' && equals == '=' && !text.empty())
    std::cout << "matched";
```

It's not as good as scanf because you'd have to verify any literals that were in the scanf string yourself. Doing it with streams will almost certainly be a lot more lines of code than scanf.

I would use scanf.

Comment: Use `cin.fail()`, not `cin.bad()` or use `cin` directly as a conditional.

Comment: I've changed it from bad() to fail(). Good call.

Answer (score 8):

You can make a simple class to verify input.

```
struct confirm_input {
    char const *str;

    confirm_input( char const *in ) : str( in ) {}

    friend std::istream &operator >>
        ( std::istream &s, confirm_input const &o ) {

        for ( char const *p = o.str; * p; ++ p ) {
            if ( std::isspace( * p ) ) {
                std::istream::sentry k( s ); // discard whitespace
            } else if ( (c = s.get() ) != * p ) {
                s.setstate( std::ios::failbit ); // stop extracting
            }
        }
        return s;
     }
};
```

usage:

```
std::cin >> x >> confirm_input( " = " ) >> y;
```

Comment: Very nice. The idea is very flexible, you could parse right into an object this way.