# How to get the character last time ungetc puts back into a FILE*

Tags: c

Suppose I have a `FILE*` created by `fopencookie`, what happens if I call `ungetc` on the `FILE*`?  Suppose I've `setvbuf` on the `FILE*` as `_IONBF` to make it unbuffered.  Looks like the fopencookie doesn't support a handler for `ungetc`.

The background is I want to run `scanf` on `istream`, see [scanf on an istream object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302160/scanf-on-an-istream-object).  One suggestion is to use `fopencookie` and I was trying to wrap `istream` as FILE* by `fopencookie`, the problem comes out is, I need to make sure the `FILE*` doesn't buffer anything, however, `scanf` will at least read one character ahead when parsing fields whose width is unknown, e.g. for %d it will continue to read until find space or end-of-line.  I assume `scanf` will put the character back to the `FILE*` by `ungetc`, in which case I need to put this character back to the `istream` as well.  Is it possible to know which character `scanf` ungets?  Thanks.

Comment: Is your name correct? Than you can do the science. Just try it out. Alternative, look at the libc sources...

Comment: Like @Deduplicator said... `Just Try It`.  You'll learn more from a 5 minute test and possible success or failure than you will from hours of reading and pondering.  You won't break it, but if you do, you get to keep the pieces to see what went wrong!   Experiment! Make mistakes!  Like Asimov said, most discoveries aren't from "`I wonder`", but from "`hmm, that's odd`".

Comment: @lornix, well, I changed the title a little bit to reflect the how-to nature of my question.

Answer (score 1):

`fopencookie` is a GNU extension which, as far as I know, exists in no other C library.

The GNU libc implementation of `stdio` is decidedly hairier than it ought to be because of an ancient (pre-EGCS, if that means anything to you) attempt to make `FILE` objects directly usable as C++ `streambuf` objects - no foolin'! - but the answer to your question may be found here: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/genops.c#l722 (the implementation of `ungetc` being named `_IO_sputbackc` is one of the remaining vestiges of that ancient attempt)  I'll quote the code, it's short:

```
722 int
723 _IO_sputbackc (fp, c)
724      _IO_FILE *fp;
725      int c;
726 {
727   int result;
728
729   if (fp->_IO_read_ptr > fp->_IO_read_base
730       && (unsigned char)fp->_IO_read_ptr[-1] == (unsigned char)c)
731     {
732       fp->_IO_read_ptr--;
733       result = (unsigned char) c;
734     }
735   else
736     result = _IO_PBACKFAIL (fp, c);
737
738   if (result != EOF)
739     fp->_flags &= ~_IO_EOF_SEEN;
740
741   return result;
742 }
```

What this is saying is that if the character pushed back is identical to the character right behind the read pointer in the `FILE` object's buffer, it just decrements the read pointer once; otherwise, `_IO_PBACKFAIL` is called.  Digging around a bit more in that directory (in particular, in [`libioP.h`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/libioP.h) and [`iofopncook.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/iofopncook.c)) reveals that `_IO_PBACKFAIL` on a `FILE` created with `fopencookie` calls [`_IO_default_pbackfail`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/genops.c#l1160)  That function is much longer and I'm not going to quote it, but what it does is allocate a special "backup buffer" and stash the character there. This backup buffer can grow to accomodate an arbitrary number of calls to `ungetc` if necessary.

So, the answer to your question is that no matter how many times you call `ungetc` in a row (or other library functions do it for you), your cookie functions will never get asked to do anything.  It's all handled internal to the `FILE`.  Per my answer to your other question, I strongly advise that you find some other approach, but for what you *were* trying to do, I don't see why you think you *need* to "put this character back to the `istream` as well."

Comment: The reason I need to get it the character back to istream is, I will mix the call to cstdio functions and iostream functions.  If I use istream after scanf, the character held by FILE won't be accessible by istream, therefore lost.  Which will be totally wrong.

Comment: Ah.  In that case, the answer is: you can't.