# Checking input to see if user has entered control-d

Tags: c, string, user-input, scanf

Pretty new to C, and I have what may be a pretty simple question. I am writing a program in C which reads a series of strings from the user. The program is supposed to do something with these strings after the user indicates that he is done entering strings. He does this by entering "Ctrl-D".

I'm having trouble figuring out how to check if the user has entered "Ctrl-D". From my initial research, it appears as though Ctrl-D is supposed to have something to do with End of File, which, it appears is not a character that I can easily check against.

I'm trying to read these strings via scanf. I have the following code (please ignore the initial strings array that eventually get returned. I know it does nothing at the moment.

```
char **get_fragments_from_user(){
    char *strings[20000];

    char tempstring[1001];
    while(true){
        printf("\n> ");
        scanf("%s", &tempstring);
        printf("\n Recorded %s", tempstring);
        if(tempstring[0] == -1) break;
    }
    return strings;
}
```

Is there an easy way to check to see if the user has entered 'Ctrl-D'?

Comment: you can register key event listener to listen to the keyboard.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr There is no such thing as a "key event listener" in standard C.  (You may be thinking of one of several different operating-system-specific APIs, but the OP is asking for advice on the use of the standard C library, not any of those.)

Comment: @Zack so i add it in a comment. just another way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Never use `scanf`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302160/scanf-on-an-istream-object/24318630#24318630)***

If you have [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline), use that.  Otherwise, use [`fgets`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).  Either way, a typed Ctrl-D (or end-of-file from redirected input) will be passed up to you as *zero characters read*, i.e. an empty string.  (If the user just presses Return without typing anything first, you get the *one*-character string "\n".)