# Loop in Function

Tags: c, function, do-while

I am coding a function to validate a number inserted by the user (between 1 and 3) and it doesn't matter what number I put the program crashes.

Here's my code:

```
    int validate(int low, int high) {
    int selection;

    do {
    scanf("%d", selection);
    if (selection < low || selection > high)
        printf("Invalid Input, try again: ");
    } while (selection > low || selection < high);

    return selection;
}
```

Anyone any idea, please?

Comment: [Never use `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302160/scanf-on-an-istream-object/24318630#24318630).  But if you insist, `&selection`, not `selection`.

Comment: consider adding error that you are getting

Comment: Add the crash message, including the trace-back.  Also, note that your while condition is always true.  Consider changing your if to "if (condition) printf ("Error") else flag = false; this lets you do the check only once and run the loop on a condition of "while flag".  Alternately, run it on "while true" and use a "break" to exit.

Answer (score 1):

While reading  scanf,  use &  with the variable

```
 int validate(int low, int high) {
    int selection;
     printf("Enter your Selection ");
      do {
            scanf("%d", &selection);
            if (selection < low || selection > high)
           {
                printf("Invalid Input, try again: ");
          }
       } while (selection < low || selection > high) ;

        return selection;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

2 bugs I see.

1. makdu, mention the scanf issue.
2. your while loop should use the && operator.

   } while (selection > low && selection < high);

Comment: Is the while logic correct @Ejaski ?   He wants to break the look  when  Selection has a value between low  and high !

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions! But why shouldn't I use scanf? what else do you use? At school I've learnt only that one..

Comment: scanf() and gets() both are susceptible to buffer overflow vulnerabilities.  Meaning you don't specify how much memory you are passing to it, so the user could possibly send more information back which would corrupt memory.  A better option is fgets().

Comment: @Ejaski Yes, and also, numeric conversions in `scanf` trigger *undefined behavior* on overflow. For what the OP is trying to do, there probably won't be an issue, but still, `fgets` (or `getline`) + `strto(u)l` is the Proper Way.