# Is there an exception for ispunct() in C?

Tags: c, string, symbols, isalpha

I want to write a code that will check the correctness of MAC address.
Input should look for example like this `D7:6E:F4:30:17:2B`.
Im thinking about using functions `isdigit()` and `isupper()`. Dont know how to make user avalaible to write " : " symbol and stop him from writting other symbols.

```
if(user input is 13:4F:60:AC:7O:DE)
    ... all good
if(user input is 14:a]:!o:0L)
    ... wrong input, retry
```

**EDIT**
According to @[Woodrow Barlow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3961271/woodrow-barlow) answer i've wrote that code:

```
int mac_address() 
    {   
        int is_valid = 1;
        printf("MAC ADDRESS:");
        fgets(mac_addr, sizeof(mac_addr), stdin); 
            if (mac_addr[sizeof(mac_addr) - 1] != '\0')
            {
                is_valid = 0;
            }
            else if (ether_aton(mac_addr) == NULL)
            {
                is_valid = 0;
                // input isn't recognizable as a MAC address
            }
            if (is_valid == 1)
            {
                system("clear");
                printf("valid!\n");
                printf("%s\n", mac_addr);
                return license_menu();
            }
            else {
                printf("invalid!\n");
                fflush(stdin);
                return 1;
            }
    }
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/ispunct

Comment: Your question is unclear, if you want to check for `:`, well check for `:`.

Comment: `:` **is** ASCII. I don't really understand your question.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking, or what your problem is. You can check that a `:` is a `:` by comparing it to `':'`. Also, ASCII is a text encoding. You're already likely using it.

Comment: `ispunct` checks for lots of other things you aren't interested in. You should use `isxdigit(ch) || ch==':'`.

Comment: The `Y4` component is weird for a string of hex.

Comment: `if (sscanf(s, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", &mac[0], &mac[1], &mac[2], &mac[3], &mac[4], &mac[5]) != 6) { /* error*/ }`

Comment: What character set are you running against?  `(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')` is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Matt `char c = '\0'; if (sscanf(s, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x%c", &mac[0], &mac[1], &mac[2], &mac[3], &mac[4], &mac[5], &c) != 6 || c != '\0') { /* error*/ }` if you want scanf to test if the string is strictly a MAC address (or you can use "strlen").

Comment: Of course there should be only letters from A to F and digits. I've wanted to focuse only on that  ' : '  first.

Comment: @Tom's will that last `%c` be read if it's the terminator character `'\0'`?

Comment: Okay, then it's better `int c; if (sscanf(s, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x%c", &mac[0], &mac[1], &mac[2], &mac[3], &mac[4], &mac[5], &c) != 6) { /* error*/ }` No need to set/check `c` value.

Comment: Also, `mac[0]..mac[5]` should be checked if they are in `0..255` range.

Comment: `unsigned char mac[6]; int i; for (i = 0; i < 17; i++) { if (i % 3 == 2 ? s[i] != ':' : !isxdigit(s[i])) break; } if (i == 17 && s[i] == '\0') { /* GOOD */ sscanf("%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx", &mac[0], &mac[1], &mac[2], &mac[3], &mac[4], &mac[5]); } else { /* BAD */ }`

Comment: @MarcoBonelli No, it will no be read. Try to read an empty string and you will read nothing, not even '\0'.

Comment: @Tom's ok, makes sense.

Comment: @Matt It's out of habit that I set/check c, because there is case where it's important. Anyway, your scanf is flawed ("AAA:A:AAA:A:AAA:A" is accepted). It's simpler to manually parse the string like Ian Abbott show it.

Comment: @Matt [The `scanf` functions are broken-as-specified and should never be used for anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302160/scanf-on-an-istream-object/24318630#24318630); please do not suggest their use, especially not to new C programmers.

Comment: @Tom's As I said there must be an additional check for a range.

Comment: @zwol `%x` is safe. And so the other arguments by the link do not apply in this particular case.

Comment: @zwol the answer you linked is about C++ and does not make any sense in this context.

Comment: @Matt `char mac[6][3] = {{0}}; sscanf(s, "%2[0-9A-F]:%2[0-9A-F]:%2[0-9A-F]:%2[0-9A-F]:%2[0-9A-F]:%2[0-9A-F]%c", mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5], &c);` then you strlen all "mac" to see if their length is strictly 2. It's a little better, although I franckly prefere the plain for loop given how you have to tweak scanf and still be obligated to do ulterior check.

Comment: @Matt `%x` is _not_ safe.  It has undefined behavior on input overflow.  If I remember correctly, the only `scanf` input formats that _don't_ have undefined behavior on invalid input are `%c` and `%NNNs` (where NNN is an explicit field width).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli That _question_ was about C++, but everything I said about `scanf` in that answer applies equally to C and C++.

Comment: @zwol By language standard `%x` is defined to be an equivalent of `strtoul`, therefore it cannot overflow in a conforming libc implementation.

Comment: `if( !(isalnum(x) || x == ':') ) { ... }`

Comment: @Matt The _syntax_ accepted by `%x` is defined to be the syntax accepted by `strtoul` with base 16, but the C standard never actually says that the conversion is performed as-if by `strtoul`, and [7.21.6.2p10](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p10) says "if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the [destination] object the behavior is undefined."  The only viable interpretation of that sentence that I can see is, for any input where `strto*` would report overflow, the corresponding `scanf` specifiers have undefined behavior.

Comment: @Matt `"%x"` can overflow and is thus potential UB.  `"%2x"` will not overflow, yet will accept inputs like questionable `" 12"`, `"-2"`, `"0"`.

Comment: Code could pedantically scan with `sscanf(s, "%1x%1x:%1x%1x:%1x%1x:%1x%1x:%1x%1x:%1x%1x%n", ...` and not risk UB. 
 Then check the length for the correct offset via the `"%n"`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198214/discussion-on-question-by-jadamian-is-there-an-exception-for-ispunct-in-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The best way to parse a MAC address or check its validity is to use [`ether_aton`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ether_aton.3.html).** MAC addresses can come in many formats, and `ether_aton` can be relied on to parse them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <netinet/ether.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    char mac_addr[64];

    while (true)
    {
        fgets(mac_addr, sizeof(mac_addr), stdin);
        if (mac_addr[sizeof(mac_addr) - 1] != '\0')
        {
            // input was too long for the buffer
            printf("invalid!\n");
        }
        else if (ether_aton(mac_addr) == NULL)
        {
            // input isn't recognizable as a MAC address
            printf("invalid!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("valid!\n");
    printf("%s\n", mac_addr);
    return 0;
}
```

---

It sounds like you're checking one character at a time, that you want to reject an invalid character immediately without waiting for the full string of input, and that you specifically want to reject MAC addresses that have lowercase letters or that use separators other than a colon. Is that accurate? I will assume you have your own reasons for doing so.

The `ispunct` function is a red herring here. There is no reason to check whether a given character is a punctuation character; what you really want to know is whether it's a colon. specifically. you can compare them directly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

bool is_valid(char ch, int i)
{
    if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
    {
        return ch == ':';
    }
    else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    struct termios old_tio, new_tio;
    const int max_len = strlen("00:00:00:00:00:00");
    char mac_addr[max_len + 1];
    char ch = '\0';
    int i = 0;
    int ret = 0;

    /* need to modify the terminal's underlying settings, because
     * by default STDIN is buffered to support backspace, etc.
     * by switching to non-buffered input, you lose a lot of basic
     * functionality like backspace.
     * that's why it's usually recommended to just read in the entire
     * line of text and then check if it's valid at the end.
     */
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &old_tio);
    new_tio = old_tio;
    new_tio.c_lflag &=(~ICANON);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &new_tio);

    for (i = 0; i < max_len; i++)
    {
        ch = getchar();
        if (!is_valid(ch, i))
        {
            printf("\ninvalid!\n");
            ret = 1;
            goto exit;
        }
        mac_addr[i] = ch;
    }
    mac_addr[max_len] = '\0';

    printf("\nvalid!\n");
    printf("%s\n", mac_addr);

exit:
    /* this is important; need to reset the terminal
     * settings to their previous value before terminating.
     */
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSANOW,&old_tio);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: error in ```char mac_addr[max_len +1] { 0 };``` ----- variable-sized object may not be initialized, that i dont understand

Comment: @jadamian i was really just trying to highlight the `is_valid` function; i assumed you already had your own user input code. but in any case i've updated the answer with a more complete example.

Comment: @jadamian i want to stress, though, that the top portion is really the best way to parse a MAC address. it's bizarre to actively reject MAC addresses that use lowercase letters, or a hyphen instead of a colon, etc.