# What does scanf("%d/%d/%d) mean in C?

Tags: c, input

```
int currD, currM, currY;
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &currD, &currM, &currY);
```

I saw this code receiving birth date in the format DD/MM/YYYY, but I wonder what's the meaning of putting '/', I know without this, it will lead to bad input because of the character '/'. So what does it actually mean?

Comment: The input has to match the `/` characters. For example `4/7/2019`. If the format string was `"%d:%d:%d"` then an acceptable input would be `4:7:2019`. To ensure the input was correctly scanned you must also check like `if(scanf("%d/%d/%d", &currD, &currM, &currY) == 3)`

Comment: @WeatherVane Can we also do this with std::cin?

Comment: No, this is C not C++.

Comment: std:cin https://stackoverflow.com/q/14330637/6699433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When encountering code that you don’t understand, and which is calling a function from a library, your first order of business is to **research the documentation for that function**. For C standard functions it’s enough to google the function name.

A good reference in this case is [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (don’t be misled by the website name, this is the C reference, not the C++ reference). It gives the function’s definition as

```
int scanf( const char *format, ... );​
```

Now look for the parameter description of the `format` parameter:

> pointer to a null-terminated character string specifying how to read the input.

The subsequent text explains how to read the format string. In particular:

> - […] character [except `%`] in the format string consumes exactly one identical character from the input stream, or causes the function to fail if the next character on the stream does not compare equal.
> - conversion specifications [in] the following format
>
>   - introductory % character
>   - conversion format specifier
>   - `d` — matches a **decimal integer**.

In other words:

`scanf` parses a textual input based on the format string. Inside the format string, `/` matches a slash in the user input literally. `%d` matches a decimal integer.

Therefore, `scanf("%d/%d/%d", …)` will match a string consisting of three integers separated by slashes, and store the number values inside the pointed-to variables.

Comment: int birthDay, birthMonth, birthYear;
char separator;
cin >> birthDay >> separator >> birthMonth >> separator >> birthYear;

I also tried this and worked.

Comment: @Dark Yes but only in C++, not in C.

Answer (score 0):

Is just the separator in the date format. The error must raise when some function searchs for those /.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of scanf is a string specifying the format of the string you want to use to store the informations in the further arguments. You can see this format string as a pattern : %d means an integer, and without the '%' it means it just has to match exactly the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Input is expected to provide like `04/07/2019`.
If input is provided only 04072019. currD alone hold the value `04072019`, currM and currY might garbage value as it is not initialised.

Answer (score 0):

It expects the input to be in the format three integers separated by two slashes ("/"). For example: `10/11/1999`.